# Tailwindcss Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

Tags: resources, load, blocked

I was working on inplementing stripe; created key.pem and cert.pem files to create a https server.
Was testing stuff and ran into this problem; the website is not rendering css.

```
Failed to load resource: 
   net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE.NotSameOriginAfterDefaultedToSameOriginByCoep
```

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css"/>
```

payment.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap:  https://js.stripe.com/v3/ 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *;**script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';** ">
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"  ></script>
<script src="checkout.js" defer></script>
```